# How to parse numerical values from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

How do I convert String in form `xx:yy` into integer form `xxyy` or float form `xx.yy`

For example If I have the following string.

```
String x = "10:30"
```

How do I get integer `1030` or float value `10.30` ?

Comment: Each primitive type has its object class like `int` has `Integer`. These classes have methods that can `parse` String to primitive types.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(str);`

Comment: You should not use Integer, Float is more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String xInt = x.replace(":","");
Integer.parseInt(xInt);
String xFloat = x.replace(":",".");
Float.parseFloat(xFloat);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] parts = x.split(":");
float value = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) + (float)Integer.parseInt(parts[1])/100;
```

or

```
Float.parseFloat(x.replaceAll(":", "."));
```